# Reinstalação do Python no Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

Sou novo no linux e estava tentando fazer um exemplo utilizando o Scrapy.

Fiz a instalação do Python 3, mas já tinha o Python 2 instalado em minha máquinha e achei que precisaria excluir o Python 2 ou pelo menos substituir.

Olhando na internet vi alguns comandos sobre isso e executei alguns até que encontrei um tutorial e quando executei os comandos listados acabei excluindo o python.

Quando ligava meu pc não aparecia barra de ferramentas e não consegui abrir absoutamente nada ! Depois de varias tentativas com recovery mode consegui entrar novamente.

Mas agora quando tento executar no terminal `sudo apt-get install` aparece esse erro: `E: The package python-apt needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it`

Gostaria de saber como posso reinstalar python

Comment: Não é preciso desinstalar o python2 eles correm paralelamente sem quaisquer problemas, isso é mal jogado

Comment: E existe alguma forma de corrigir ? @Miguel

Comment: Tente fazer `sudo apt-get udpate`, e depois siga http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu ou https://gist.github.com/lukaslundgren/2659457 ou ainda http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/linux/. Tem várias coisas sobre isso: https://www.google.pt/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=reinstall+python2.7&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9ITFV7z1Icjv8Aee46SAAw

Answer (score 1):

Bom, a essa altura, é mais provavel que você precise re-instalar seu ubuntu.

O Python2 é uma parte integral de um sistema Linux moderno (não apenas do Ubuntu),e, como você percebeu, o sistema não tem como funcionar sem ele.

O gerenciamento automático de pacotes ainda desinstalou todos os pacotes qeu dependem do Python2 - então o seu sistema está realmente quebrado.

Os Linux são feitos de forma que não só é possível, como é comum ter o Python2 e Python3 instalados lado a lado - mas, mais ainda, é comum que cada projeto que você vá fazer possa ter sua própria cópia do Python, de forma que não conflite com as dependências do próprio sistema. Isso tanto pode ser uma cópia compilada por você mesmo desde o código fonte, como uma cópia "virtual" com o uso do Virtualenv.  O Uso do virtualenv, por exemplo, evita que se você precisar de um pacote qualquer do Python numa versão diferente da disponibilizada pelo sistema (por exemplo, uma versão mais nova do scrapy), você possa instala-la de forma isolada. Em geral pacotes menores não quebram tanto o  sistema quanto arrancar o Python 2 na froça bruta, mas ainda podem deixar várias coisas quebradas.